# Effective Content Security Policy definition for YouTube.com

Tags: content-security-policy

I defined content security policies for one of the application which uses JavaScript files from `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` as follows;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="script-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com;
child-src https://www.youtube.com;">
```

Now on chrome dev tools, I get the error below:

> Refused to load the script 'https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflaaT2_k/www-widgetapi.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com".

Should I add `https://s.ytimg.com` to the content security policy settings?

If yes, does it constitute a security risk as one cannot guarantee whether it may change over time?

How can I effectively define content security policies for YouTube?

Answer (score 5):

Yes that's exactly what you need to do. Ytimg is YouTube's CDN for static files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it how CSP works ? Cause the api which i reference and know sure is https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api but how can be sure that youtube will not change  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflaaT2_k/www-widgetapi.js to a different domain which is loaded from the know script.

Comment: Yes unfortunately that's one of the risks of CSP :-( It would be nice if publishers like YouTube told you the CSP policy they required and committed to sticking to it unless notifying changes in advance. Without that it's a bit of a risk to be honest. If you deliver your CSP as a http header configured on a web server then can provide a report-uri parameter where you are informed of violations of your policy. Unfortunately this is not available in the meta element. And reports are very noisy anyway due to many browser extensions injecting javascript!